# Ubuntu installation gives black screen with no solution

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, 22.04

I have seen many threads describing similar issues, but none of the answers given have worked for me:

I have Windows 10 on UEFI mode. I wanted to dual boot with Ubuntu 22.04, so I created a USB with GPT.

Processor: 11th Gen Intel Core i5-1100F
Graphics Card: Radeon AMD 6700XT
Motherboard: ASUS Prime 560M-A

The first time booting onto the USB drive was great, I was able to almost complete the installation, but once I hit "install" after creating all the partitions, I got an error (blaming the USB drive), and the installation shut down.

After this, any time I hit "Try or Install Ubuntu" in GRUB, I get a black screen. Safe Graphics mode doesn't do anything either. The most info I can provide is that one time I waited around half an hour and I got an error message that I couldn't capture. I tried with Ubuntu 20.04 but that didn't work either. I must have tried more than 10 times already.

I am not sure what I can do, every solution I find online either doesn't work or doesn't apply to my situation.

Please let me know if I can provide any more info.

Comment: When you downloaded the install media did you check the checksum? Since the first failure did you recreate the install media on the usb drive. Have you tried a different usb drive. It is possible the original usb drive has become faulty.

Comment: Hi there, 

Indeed, the solution was getting a new USB drive. I had done many installs with the previous one and other "worse" USB drives, so I really didn't think that would be the issue. But here we are now with the new installation, already a success :) Thanks for the help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot)